# First post full width without Sidebar

Tags: theme-development

I want to create a template where the first (latest) post is shown full width respectively without a sidebar. All the following posts should have been displayed normally, like [here](http://www.kayture.com)

```
1st POST

2nd POST | SIDEBAR
3rd POST | SIDEBAR
4th POST | SIDEBAR
...
```

Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also doe like below code snippet:

```
$flag=0;
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'title',
'order'   => 'DESC',); 
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
{
  the_post();
  if($flag==0)
  {
     // you first post's title, content etc
     $flag=1;
  }
  else
  {
      //rest of your post's title, sidebar, etc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create some counter, that will count all your posts in your query.

Than, wrap the first post with full width div. For example:

Title and content




Content